# Free scripting for Android, Ios, Windows Phone (Symbian would be nice)

Tags: gui, software-testing

I am developing under Windows. The user will connect a smart-phone by USB which will communicate with an app on the PC. I do not have access to the code of the Smartphone app.

For regression testing during development, I would like to write some scripts to simulate user action at the ´phone & test the result. For reasons that I won´t go into, I have to simulate the human user; I cannot simply simulate the 'phone.

E.g., Script says - find a button with the label "push me", simulate a click to it and expect an alert saying "Please don't push the button again".

Unless it gets more platforms covered, I would strongly prefer scripting over macro recording (especially as it let´s me check the result).

I presume that I am looking for something which has a native app for all platforms, or a script which can run on all platforms, which will interpret and run my test scripts(?).

Something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), but for smart-phones.

Android & Ios == "must have", Windows 'phone == "nice to have", Symbian == "a bonus to have, for legacy support".

---

[Update] After a lot of googling, the best free solutions that I have found cover only Android & iOS ... http://appurify.com/    and http://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk community edition. I will finish searching, then evaluate these & report back.

Hmm, I don´t like this requirement of MonkeyTalk, because I do not have access to the source code of the Smartphone app: "MonkeyTalk Agent - library that must be added to app to enable testing".

More explicitly, “Can I test an app without the source code? No. You must install the MonkeyTalk Agent into the app under test during the build process, which requires access to the app source code“.

The best (and expensive!!) commerical solutions is [SeeTest Automation Tool](http://de.slideshare.net/videotuition/see-test-automation) Features : Mobile (Android, iOS, Blackberry, Windows, Symbian)   BUT   $3,500 / year !!

This looks good too, but I can´t see the pricing   http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/index.php

Comment: The pricing for Squish I snow online and it too is  ... @#£%$!! ouch!  Otoh, as a portion of your salary ...  It all depends how much your company is willing to pay. I don't find a month or two's salary prohibitive

Answer (score 1):

Free tools I know of are:

- [AutoItMonkey](https://github.com/ohtejera/AutoItMonkey)
  and
- [Culebra](http://dtmilano.blogspot.gr/2014/11/culebra-gui-to-automatically-generate.html)

I have tested Culebra and it works but was very slow (it may be better now).

---

You can also find various solutions in the following presentation

- [5 best automation tools for testing Android applications (Slideshare)](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/MindfireSolutions/introduction-to-mobileautomation)
  and
- [5 best automation tools for testing Android applications (Software testing help)](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/5-best-automation-tools-for-testing-android-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using '[Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en)' with conjunction with built-in system command `input` to get scripts running in mobile games. Given 'input tap', 'input text', 'input keyevent' you have ability to create pretty much any interaction. You don't have button-finding capabilities though, you need to know x,y coords - or use 'sendevent' instead.

The free version should be sufficient for short scripts. My scripts grew so much I had to upgrade to 'pro' (which was about $5 at that time?)

Or you could just write shell scripts utilizing the 'input' command. Apps like [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) provide a tolerable access to the Linux layer of Android system.

Note using the 'input' command, and generally everything that hijacks the UI like you intend requires the device to be rooted.

A fragment of my 'clicker' script from 'automate' - clicking on random points within designated rectangle on screen in game, just 'grinding'.

[image]
[image]