# Automation software for Android application

Tags: android, automation

I'm looking for a free software to automate a procedure with an Android Application.

At the moment i'm using UIPath (community edition) along with Bluestacks (Android emulator software for gaming), but designing scripts to automate what I'm trying to accomplish seems to be a little tricky. Plus, Bluestacks comes rooted and, since the device would be under MDM, this isn't an option, because rooting the device would make it non-compliant.

Specifically, I'm trying to automate a procedure for daily reservation in an application I already have. 
The application involves the selection of day, time of day, duration of the reservation (all are performed by tapping/swiping to select the time of day).

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That very much depends on what you want to automate, and based on what triggers it should work – so please [edit] your question and provide some more details. You're also welcome to check with my list of [Automation apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation).

Comment: Greetings Izzy, thanks a lot for your help. I've edited the question, hope it provides more insight on what I'm trying to achieve. In the meantime, I'll check out your list of applications.

Comment: Uh, not really (sorry). I'm a bit confused now: are you looking for a reservation app? Or for some app that controls a reservation app you already have? The latter would at least require elevated permissions (device-admin or accessibility) to emulate taps and swipes.

Comment: Ok, I already have a reservation app, and I'm trying to automate the procedure. 
Unfortunately though i won't be able to root the device because it's under MDM compliance, and this would make it non-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there is simply nothing to beat the excellent [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/), so you are looking for something similar (it will be heard to match).

All that I can find is Google's [Scripting Layer for Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_Layer_for_Android).

Take a look at [its GitHub page](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a).

However, it is not a standalone app as such. It simply lets you code various scripting languages on Android.

> Currently supported languages are:
>    •Python using CPython
>    •Perl
>    •Ruby using JRuby
>    •Lua
>    •BeanShell
>    •JavaScript using Rhino
>    •Tcl
>    •Rexx using BRexx

would that help you?

Btw, do you want to automate a true native Android app? Something browser based might be easier to automate.

Comment: See also [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/free-scripting-for-android-ios-windows-phone-symbian-would-be-nice)

Comment: Hi Mawg, thanks for your response. I'm not trying to emulate a native android application, but a third party application which is under MDM. For the MDM part i think i found a solution to "evade" it, but i believe I will still need the device to NOT be rooted.

Comment: I don't even know what MDM is, but if it's important, best update your question :-) Also, if you find a solution, please post an answer and accept it, as that will help others